# Access Kafka Cluster Outside GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

I'm currently trying to access the kafka cluster(bitnami) from my local machine, however the problem is that even after exposing the required host and ports in server.properties and adding firewall rules to allow 9092 port it just doesn't connect.

I'm running 2 broker and 1 zookeeper configuration.

> Expected Output: Producer.bootstrap_connected() should return True.

Actual Output: False

**server.properties**

```
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://gcp-cluster-name:9092
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN`
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

**Consumer.py**

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json

sasl_mechanism = 'PLAIN'
security_protocol = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT'

# Create a new context using system defaults, disable all but TLS1.2
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

consumer = KafkaConsumer('organic-sense',
                         bootstrap_servers='<server-ip>:9092',
                         value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')),
                         ssl_context=context,
                         sasl_plain_username='user',
                         sasl_plain_password='<password>',
                         sasl_mechanism=sasl_mechanism,
                         security_protocol = security_protocol,
                         )

print(consumer.bootstrap_connected())
for data in consumer:
    print(data)
```

Comment: Please use text, not images, for your configuration snippets. It makes it much easier for people to read. Can you update your question to show how you're connecting to the cluster and the error that you're getting?

Comment: Also did you read https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/ ?

Comment: Hi, Thank for responding. Actually, I resolved the issue there was authentication problem with kafka client and the bitnami server was crashing upon connecting producer. Now, I'm successfully able to run producer and consumer on cluster. The problem is now , when I'm using the Consumer code it's returning true but the data is not being received by consumer. same for the Producer.

Comment: Yes, I did but I was not able to configure properly.